# LinkedIn API is there a way to get skill endorsements

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

I am trying to build a small application where i can get the skill endorsements. I have been successfully able to retrieve skills, but as I read developers forum there were many informations that it is not even possible for now.

Is there anyway to get endorsements number for each skill?

Comment: No. //Comments cannot be shorter than 15 chars

Answer (score 2):

It seems NOT possible. [This forum post](https://developer.linkedin.com/thread/2663) suggest there are fields like `:(skills:(skill,proficiency,years)` but I wasn't able to retrieve anything else then `name` (as mentioned in [Linkedin Docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields#skills)).